# The name LayoutRoot does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I am getting this erorr code: "The name LayoutRoot does not exist in the current context".

I haven't write any control in Xaml file yet, because I can't find the control "LayoutRoot" in toolBox. How can I solve this problem?

This is my code:

```
using(SkeletonFrame frame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
{
if(frame != null)
{
Polyline figure;
Brush userBrush;
Skeleton skeleton;
**LayoutRoot.Children.Clear();**
frame.CopySkeletonDataTo(this._FrameSkeletons);
for(int i = 0; i < this._FrameSkeletons.Length; i++)
{
skeleton = this._FrameSkeletons[i];
if(skeleton.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
{
userBrush = this._SkeletonBrushes[i % this._SkeletonBrushes.Length];
//Draws the skeleton’s head and torso
joints = new [] { JointType.Head, JointType.ShoulderCenter,
JointType.ShoulderLeft, JointType.Spine,
JointType.ShoulderRight, JointType.ShoulderCenter,
JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipLeft,
JointType.Spine, JointType.HipRight,
JointType.HipCenter });
**LayoutRoot.Children.Add**(CreateFigure(skeleton, userBrush, joints));
//Draws the skeleton’s left leg
joints = new [] { JointType.HipLeft, JointType.KneeLeft,
JointType.AnkleLeft, JointType.FootLeft };
**LayoutRoot.Children.Add**(CreateFigure(skeleton, userBrush, joints));
//Draws the skeleton’s right leg
joints = new [] { JointType.HipRight, JointType.KneeRight,
JointType.AnkleRight, JointType.FootRight };
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(CreateFigure(skeleton, userBrush, joints));
//Draws the skeleton’s left arm
joints = new [] { JointType.ShoulderLeft, JointType.ElbowLeft,
JointType.WristLeft, JointType.HandLeft };
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(CreateFigure(skeleton, userBrush, joints));
//Draws the skeleton’s right arm
joints = new [] { JointType.ShoulderRight, JointType.ElbowRight,
JointType.WristRight, JointType.HandRight };
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(CreateFigure(skeleton, userBrush, joints));
```

Answer (score 3):

you may create some panel like control in xaml or in the code itself

xaml example

```
<Window x:Class="CSharpWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
    </Canvas>
</Windows>
```

or in code like

```
Canvas LayoutRoot = new Canvas();
using(SkeletonFrame frame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
{
    ...
}
//add LayoutRoot to the parent control etc.
```

I have used Canvas as the panel with assumption that you are adding some figures to it. You may choose the appropriate control as desired.

Comment: ThankssS !! Now, is OK, no erorre!